# What is the Dew Factor? How does it affect the match?

Tags: cricket, terminology

Recently, during the pre match discussion between India and England in Ranchi, I heard about *Dew Factor*. They said that *Dew Factor* will affect the match. Before that I newer heard about it. So what is the *Dew Factor*? And how does it affect the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dew is basically moisture that forms during late evenings. A layer of moisture can be noticed on the grass field during day-night/night games.

Dew affects the bowling team majorly. A wet ball is harder to grip, thereby putting bowlers to a disadvantage. This is most notable in finger-spin bowlers who depend on gripping the ball to get the required amount of turn. Additionally, due to lack of grip, it is harder for the bowlers to maintain the desired line+length as compared to a non-dew environment.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://www.questioncricket.com/2009/05/dew-factor.html).

Yes, dew (wetness in the environment) factor can change the direction of a match. Many-a-times, captains choose batting or bowling according to the dew factor or the moisture in the air. If dew is more, there will be less turn (for spinners) and for fast bowlers, the ball is straight. Therefore, the batsman is at an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Another disadvantage of the dew factor is that it makes hitting boundaries difficult.
The ball travels much slower on the wet turf, so often brilliantly timed shots do not reach the fence, and the batsmen have to settle for 2 or 3 runs.

Comment: Balances things I hope.